# C UDP socket connection isn't assigning the ports right way

Tags: c, sockets, struct, udp

I have the following schema:

```
program in terminal A (<process 1>):

Stored:
    <process 1>: <portnumber 51340>
    <process 2>: <portnumber 58432>

program in terminal B (<process 2>):

Stored:
    <process 1>: <portnumber 51340>
    <process 2>: <portnumber 58432>
```

So I have an UDP socket connection between them to send and recieve an struct:

```
  int socketID = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr = {0};

  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(0);
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  int rc = bind(socketID, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  socklen_t sockaddrlen = sizeof(servaddr);
  int getsocket = getsockname(socketID, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, &sockaddrlen);
```

Before I do the sendto I do:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Using procPort %d\n", idPort);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(<portNumber 58432>);
fprintf(stdout, "Using port %d\n", &toSocketID.sin_port);
sendto(fromSocketID, &msg, sizeof(struct message), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&toSocketID, toSocketIDLen);
```

And it prints:

```
Using procPort 58432
Using port 58432
```

All is OK until here. Here's the problem, when, before I do the recvfrom I do:

```
servaddr.sin_port = htons(<portNumber 58432>);
fprintf(stdout, "Using procPort %d\n", <portNumber 58432>);
fprintf(stdout, "Using port %d\n", servaddr.sin_port);

struct message * recievedMsg = malloc(sizeof(struct message));

recieveResult = recvfrom(socketID, recievedMsg, sizeof(*recievedMsg), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
```

And it prints:

```
Using procPort 58432
Using port 16612
```

And it does not recieve the message, I think this is because of the magic change in the port, that 16612 that doesn't appear anywhere in my program. But it could also be because of the configuration. Do you see what's wrong? I'm losing my mind.

Edit:

Some of you are arguing about byte swapping.
Other outputs for the second part:

```
Using procPort 50912
Using port 57542

Using procPort 33592
Using port 14467

Using procPort 42115
Using port 33700
```

Comment: You're missing `ntohs(servaddr.sin_port)` - 16612 when byte-swapped is 58432.

Comment: Does that mean that the configuration is OK? If it is, why it doesn't work? What do I have to change?

Comment: @SteveFriedl `hex(16612) == 0x40e4` and `hex(58432) == 0xe3e6`. Doesn't look like byte swap to me.

Comment: @user58697 I think you have a typo; 0xE3E6 is 58342, which is a transposition of the value of interest.

Comment: I update with other inputs and outputs for you to check if it is byte swap or not

Comment: @sanz_sual - when you say "does not receive the message" - how does this manifest itself? Hangs? system call returns failure? Garbage data?

Comment: It just freezes. I've a fprintf after the recvfrom and it doesn't shows, neither the rest of the code after that in the process that is recieving

Comment: This doesn't look right: `fprintf(stdout, "Using port %d\n", &toSocketID.sin_port);` - the `&` looks wrong.

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, "Using port %d\n", &toSocketID.sin_port);` that's because that line is on a function, a "sendMessage function" and I pass the const struct sockaddr * toSocketID as an argument

Comment: Do you get a clean compile when you enable all warnings?

Comment: @SteveFriedl Typo indeed. You are right.

Comment: Yes I do, one that's about the recvfrom:

`sizeof(servaddr)`

There. It says that recvfrom creates a pointer from an int without conversion.

Comment: But if I change it to `sizeof(&servaddr)` it says the same. Do you think that if I change it to `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` I will fix it?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't xd

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, "Using port %d\n", &toSocketID.sin_port);` is wrong. I don't understand your reaction to @SteveFriedl 's comment. You got it wrong, simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These snippets make it hard to really get a big picture, but I'm pretty sure your compiler is telling you what the problem is.

```
struct sockaddr_in servaddr = {0};
...
receiveResult = recvfrom(socketID,
                         receivedMsg, sizeof(*receivedMsg),
                         0,
                         (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
```

As the compiler notes, you're passing a last parameter as an integer, but it's supposed to be a *pointer*.  The idea is that you tell `recvfrom` how big your address structure is, but on return the kernel tells YOU how much of that structure it's using.

I'm surprised it's not faulting due to giving a small integer as a pointer.

Also, the second-to-last parameter shouldn't be `const`.

Change this to (formatting just for readability here):

```c
socklen_t addrsize = sizeof servaddr;

receiveResult = recvfrom(socketID,
                        receivedMsg, sizeof *receivedMsg,
                        0,
                        (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, &addrsize);
```

**EDIT**: Moral of the story: always turn on compiler warnings and *understand them*, not just make them go away. Throwing in random casts will likely silence the compiler but it will remove the good advice.

When you use a cast, you're telling the compiler "trust me", and if you lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge.

**EDIT 2**: Other things in the code can't be right.

I can't see what the type of `toSocketID` is, but I can't see any construction where this would be right:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Using port %d\n", &toSocketID.sin_port);
```

I would imagine `ntohs(toSocketID->sin_port)` seems more plausible.